# About longitudinal - transversal decomposition of vector fields

Tags: field-theory, vector-fields

When analyzing the stability of vector fields, a longitudinal+transversal decomposition is usually performed. Such a decomposition looks like:

$$A_\mu = B_\mu + \partial_\mu \phi \tag{1}$$

where $B_\mu$ is said to be transversal because it fulfils $\partial_\mu B^\mu=0$.

In principle, I would agree on a splitting of the type:

$$A_\mu = B_\mu + L_\mu$$

where $B_\mu$ is still the transversal part, and $L_\mu$ is the rest (that we may call the longitudinal part).

The thing is that I do not see why $L_\mu$ can *always* be written as the partial of some scalar. Under which hypotheses is this true? I have not found anywhere a detailed explanation of this.

---

Some further ideas that came to my mind:

- My first attempt was trying to see (1) as a kind of Hodge decomposition. However, it is well-known that the latter is only well-defined in (+...+) signature, not in Lorentzian one.
- All of this is also confusing, because (1) is sometimes mixed in the literature with the notion of Stueckelberg fields, which are used to restore local symmetries. However, when one applies the Stueckelberg trick, one just performs a substitution of the type
  $$A_\mu \to A_\mu + \partial_\mu \psi$$
  where $\psi$ is a new field that can be absorbed by fixing the gauge of the new symmetry. Notice that here no transversal vector has been introduced (!).

Comment: [Helmholtz decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition).